# Finding Max Value from Key/Value Object pairs Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, max, key-value

I'm stuck on why my Javascript findMaxObjectValue function will not work.  Here's what I've come up with:

```
function findMaxObjectValue(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (obj.a > obj.b) ? a : b;
    }, obj[a]);
}
```

When I run this:

```
findMaxObjectValue([{Alex: 1}, {Katie: 2}, {Nora: 3}, {Dana: 4}])
```

It returns `'3'`, when I am hoping for `'4'`... All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are reducing the keys and not the values.  It is comparing Alex, Katie, Nora and Dana.  Nora comes last lexicographically, so that is the answer.

If you want to sort by the values 1, 2, 3, 4, then use the values() method, not the keys() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`

```js
function findMaxObjectValue(obj) {

  var objLargestVal = Object.values(obj).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return (obj[a] > obj[b]) ? a : b;
  });
  for (var keys in objLargestVal) {
    return objLargestVal[keys]
  }
}


console.log(findMaxObjectValue([{
  Alex: 1
}, {
  Katie: 2
}, {
  Nora: 3
}, {
  Dana: 4
}]))
```